# Positioning divs next to eachother

Tags: css, positioning, css-position, css-float

I'm trying to create a very simple jQuery slider; however, to get started, I wanted to position my divs next to eachother instead of underneath eachother so I could animate the 'left:' css value. I'm dumb and completely failing at this though. I don't get it.

Here's an example of the code I'm playing with:

http://jsfiddle.net/YUQWx/1/

I don't understand why they stay below eachother instead of going next to eachother. The `left:` seems to be getting ignored? I'm probably missing out on something here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It turns out I'm stupid and can't type. +1 for those who bothered spending their time on me >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're spelling `.scrolling-content` with a dash in the CSS, but with an underscore (`<div id="zone_a" class="scrolling_content">`) in the HTML.  Fix the spelling, and you'll be fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `float: left;`.  Change the following:

```
#scrollzone
{
    width: 700px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;    
}

#zone_a, #zone_b, #zone_c
{
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;    
    top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YUQWx/3/  I added it to the #zone_a, #zone_b selector, doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: Updated my answer with the changes to the original jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

You need to float the divs. Something like:

```
#div1 { 
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

#div2{ 
    float:left;
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YUQWx/3/ doesn't seem to be working? Or am I adding it to the wrong selector.

Comment: You need to use selector names specific to your own problem, I was simply providing a generalization.